# GUI programming without OOP

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, gtk, ada

I have a background in structural programming (Pascal,Ada) and now I have been programming an app in Java because I needed to use a given package that was only available for Java,C++ and Python. I chose Java, but I think it was not the best idea as I am not into OOP and I am programming it in a structural way, this is, only with methods and the main program,avoiding to generate objects and those Java things.

Now that I have the "app" running in the windows console I need to generate a GUI to operate it, but before going to hell with Java and objects I would prefer to change to another programming language that permits me to constract the GUI with my structural programming mindset (if it is possible).

I have read that Tkinter in Python and GTkAda in Ada could be my saviours. In case of not being possible I guess I should try to get into OOP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This will probably get closed because it is opinion based.  It depends so much on what you need to do in the future, GUI programming is particularly suitable for object orientation.  Python is object oriented as well but you can achieve some things without it.  In my opinion python is a gentler introduction to OO than Java.

Comment: The thing is this is probably the last time I will need to build something like this, so I would like to avoid as much as possible entering in OO

Comment: I built a full GUI without OOP that was 600 lines of code. This was a complex note taking tool I made as my first program. It is just a matter of making sure you define your functions and variables in the correct order as well as using `global` where you need it. That said the OOP method is much easier to work with and maintain once you get use to it. When I finally learned how to write classes and use OOP properly I have never been back to writing Python GUI in a non OOP way. Except for some very small examples on answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GtkAda is also object-oriented, and so is any other high-level GUI toolkit I've seen so far, so I don't think you can avoid object-oriented programming for the GUI, unless you use a more low-level approach.

Two more low-level approaches are:

1. An HTTP/HTML based interface.
2. Using the X protocol to talk directly with an X server.

Both of these approaches can be used with Ada, and probably also with Python.  I don't know for sure if Python can do the necessary low-level formatting to talk with an X server, but it must be possible somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I can't avoid it I think I will use NetBeans, as it generates most of the code when dragging the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use Python, try out [PySimpleGUI](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org).  There are objects in use, but you don't have to do any object programming.  You can copy and paste the "design patterns" without having to know exactly what they do. It was developed with beginners in mind, but can also support advanced, customized window layouts.  Look at the [Cookbook](http://cookbook.pysimplegui.org) for code examples.  You mostly need to learn how to do a "layout".  You will not have to write the word "class" in your code, promise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look at it